# PHP: fopen No such file or directory error

Tags: php, fopen

I am trying to access the falt files from another server to one server through fopen , i am able to access those file through file path in browser like

file://external-web.miami123.org/test/test123. but when i am trying to access those through fopen in php code i am getting no such file or directory .here is my code .

```
$arrContextOptions=array(
            "ssl"=>array(
                "verify_peer"=>false,
                "verify_peer_name"=>false,
            ),
        );

$file =  fopen("external-web.miami123.org/test/test123",'r','1',stream_context_create($arrContextOptions));
print_r($file);
exit;
```

Comment: is a webserver on the external server, or are you accessing the file system directly?

Comment: and: are you working on Windows / Linux system?

Comment: yeah the webserver is external server ,i am trying to access it through fopen

Comment: i am working on windows @ ivo

Comment: if you want to access it as a file (not on a webserver, as you implicitly suggest using file:// )  `\\external-web.miami123.org/test/test123` And you may have to double that to 4 backslashes in php

Comment: so you are saying i have to access it like fopen("file://external-web.miami123.org/test/test123",'r','1',stream_context_create($arrContextOptions)); @IvoP

Comment: I am not sure about the file:// way. I am more a Linux user, and would not need that. But I know when mapping other servers in Windows one uses these \\Servername\ way to indicate a servername

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without specifying a protocol, PHP will search for a file on your computer named `test123` under `./external-web.miami123.org/test`.

TLDR: Use http: `http://external-web.miami123.org/test/test123`

Comment: when i am using the http i am getting HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Comment: Well then your path is wrong and points to a location that does not exist. 404 is a perfectly valid http response. Check if it is correct.

Comment: but i am able to access the files through browser a i mentioned above

Comment: check with your browser the `http://` address and with your code the `file://` address. Is there any possibility that you access your own computer?